# Range of Edm.Time type for OData v2

Tags: odata

I would like to ask for the format of Edm.Time type in OData v2.
Based on the [6. Primitive Data Types of OData v2](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/), it said "ranging from 0:00:00.x to 23:59:59.y" for Edm.Time.
Meaning that PT00H00M00S until PT23H59M59S will be acceptable. So PT24H00M00S is not acceptable?
Correct me if I'm incorrect.

Comment: I think questions about the spec are answered more quickly here: https://groups.google.com/g/odata-discussion **or** in [SAP Community](https://answers.sap.com/questions/ask.html) by adding `@ralf.handl` in the question.